# 3 Pane SlidingPaneLayout (Evernote 5.1 Android)

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, evernote

I've been attempting to replicate the 3-pane style layout in Evernote 5.1 for Android:

[image]

Sliding the middle pane will cover the content on the left. Sliding the top most pane will cover the whole screen. Content on each pane can be interacted with regardless of pane position (unless the top pane is covering everything, of course).

The closest I have been able to come is by using a SlidingPaneLayout - however, more than 2 children are not supported and I end up with something akin to the Hangouts app.

Adding a 3rd child, or nesting a 2nd SlidingPaneLayout within the first results in odd behaviour with regard to both pane positioning and in the case of the latter, swipe behaviour.

How could I go about successfully adding a 3rd pane in this scenario?

Comment: this appears to be `SlidingMenu` (probably a 3rd party sliding menu since it moves the content) with `SlidingPaneLayout`

Comment: tyczj - thank you so much... I honestly can't believe I tried everything EXCEPT just putting a SlidingPaneLayout as the ContentBehind of a SlidingMenu - it's really so obvious and I completely missed it as a solution.

Now I just need to somehow disable the one-touch pane toggle that seems inherent to SlidingPaneLayout and SlidingMenu and I'm golden - though that's something I'll work out myself.

If you would submit your suggestion as the answer to this question, I will glady accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they have a `SlidingMenu` possibly a third party one since it moves the whole contentview with a `SlidingPaneLayout`